# Where I can find a list of available fonts with mathspec package?

Tags: xetex, overleaf, unicode-math, mathspec

I want to change the math fonts from the standard latex fonts to a font that matches more closely to my text font (as I am using a custom font for the text). However, I do not want to use the text font in math mode because the text font has issues with overlapping etc...

I believe the solution is to just choose an existing math font that goes well with my text font. Here is a minimal example of how I am doing this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}$, $\pi \in \Pi$, and $\gamma \in [0,1]$. Now, see the following example equation:
\begin{align}
    J(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \gamma^i c(\mathbf{x}_i, \pi(\mathbf{x})) \right]
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

In the example, I use Latin Modern Math, but how do I see a list of the available fonts for `mathspec`?

Note: I am compiling using XeLaTeX using Overleaf.

Comment: `mathspec` is a package specifically for using *text* fonts for mathematics (As you already realized, this is always a bit problematic and it is better to use a real math font instead). If you want to use a math font for math, you should use `unicode-math` instead.

Comment: @AlanMunn This does indeed answer the question I asked. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Okay. I see. How can I set to unicode math? The math fonts in my equation seem to be set as the text font after I change the main text font to a custom type. This is why I was using `mathspec` as I was able to get the math font to show properly.

Comment: @Ralff Replace `{mathspec}` with `{unicode-math}` and remove `(Digits,Latin,Greek)`. (Latin Modern Math looks rather similar to the default math setup though, so it's not very obvious. But the font is not supposed to look like in your `mathspec` example where most operators come from other fonts and default letters are upright.)